# how to do looping (for) in dart flutter when calculate distance of 10 locations?

Tags: loops, for-loop, flutter, dart, geolocation

I am trying to get distance of 10 locations... but I don't get idea how to do it using looping `for`.. here is the code

```
final double distance1 = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        lat1, long1, endLat, endLong);
....
final double distance10 = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        lat10, long10, endLat, endLong);
```

is there a way to do looping for 10 distance and save the value of 10 distances inside array

Comment: Basically do you want to add distance1..10 to your array right? or you asking about iterating lat1 and long1?

Comment: Should be fairly easy if you have lat1..10 and long1..10 as two lists instead of separate variables. Then you can just make a list of distance which contains the result of looping through the lat and long lists.

Comment: Hi...thank you for  sharing the knowledge..I find the answer by doing this ```final distance = List<double>.filled(10, 0);``` and then I am doing looping by defining value like this...```for (int i = 0; i < totalDistance.length; i++) {distance[i] = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        lat[i], long[i], endLat, endLong);}```

Comment: Sounds right. A more simple approach for the list is to just create the list like `final distance = <double>[];` and then use `distance.add(await Geolocator().distanceBetween( lat[i], long[i], endLat, endLong));` to add each distance to the end of the list.

Comment: that's very good.. clean and simple.. thanks for your help :D